# Google Cloud VM Instance Name Change

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hostname

I would like to change the VM instance name on the Google Cloud admin portal to reflect the new names I have given various servers. Is there a way via the GUI to do so, or does this need to be done via the Google Shell?

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following command:

```
$ gcloud beta compute instances set-name CURRENT_NAME —zone=ZONE —new-name=NEW_NAME
```

You'll need to shut down the VM first. And note that the Developer Console UI won't be aware of the rename until you do a browser refresh.

Answer (score 0):

This is still not possible but you can add your vote here:
https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/302595-compute-engine/suggestions/10641504-renaming-vm?page=3&per_page=20